# WCF Authentication NT Challenge response

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security, wcf-client

How can I get my console app to connect with an IIS hosted WCF service when basic and/or windows authentication is switched on and anonymous authentication turned off?

The site is internal and stringent security is not required. There is no domain controller. However, I need to turn off anonymous access.

I have searched for days and have tried many methods including using a self hosted certificate and overriding the certification validation, overriding the `UserNameValidator` and using `client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredentials.UserName` or `client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName`. None of these have worked.

I am at a point where it would be nice if someone would be so kind as to look and run the code and help me get the sample running with authentication.

I have taken the liberty of uploading a sandbox solution containing, HostWebSite, ClientConsole and API projects.

I have hosted the zip file on my Windows Live SkyDrive: [WCF_Authentication.zip](http://lhsnxg.sn2.livefilestore.com/y1pJNUFC9azpUdM3E7oq-1_R5o3dE-94eD3O7CuBLfCNUsChAVbTg-0OzUvNEMAQXsqBcVmJnpdrRY3QzRMlBMvRQ/WCF_Authentication.zip?download&psid=1)

Some small setup steps.

1. I added to the hosts file `127.0.0.1 hostwebsite.local`
2. I added a website to IIS
   -- location: `HostWebSite project root`,
   -- binding: `hostwebsite.local`
   -- app pool: `Classic 4.0 app pool`.
3. Applied security `Everyone` read access to the HostWebSite project directory.
4. Verify can see service `http://hostwebsite.local/services/EchoService.svc`
5. Verify the console echoes back hello world.
6. Then turn off anonymous via IIS / Authentication and turn on either basic and/or windows authentication.

**thank you**

**For the benefit of readers, I have included code snippets here**
**Project: API**

```
namespace API.Contract
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IEcho
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string SendEcho(string message);
    }
}
namespace API.Proxy
{
    public class EchoProxy : IEcho
    {
        public string SendEcho(string message)
        {
            return string.Concat("You said: ", message);
        }
    }
}
namespace API.Service
{
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    public class EchoService : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<IEcho>, IEcho
    {

        public EchoService()
        {
        }

        public EchoService(string endpointConfigurationName) :
            base(endpointConfigurationName)
        {
        }

        public EchoService(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) :
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
        {
        }

        public EchoService(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) :
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
        {
        }

        public EchoService(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) :
            base(binding, remoteAddress)
        {
        }

        public string SendEcho(string message)
        {
            return base.Channel.SendEcho(message);
        }
    }
}
```

**Project: ClientConsole**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    EchoService client = new EchoService("WSHttpBinding_IEcho");

    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine(client.SendEcho("Hello World"));
        client.Close(); // i tried putting this in the finally block but the client would close in an errored state it said.
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {

    }


    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Client Config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IEcho" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                allowCookies="false">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                    enabled="false" />
                <security mode="Message">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                        algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://hostwebsite.local/Services/EchoService.svc/services/EchoService.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IEcho"
            contract="API.Contract.IEcho" name="WSHttpBinding_IEcho">
            <identity>
                <servicePrincipalName value="host/mikev-ws" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Project: HostWebSite**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <!-- SERVER -->
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        <service name="API.Proxy.EchoProxy" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
            <endpoint address="/services/EchoService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="API.Contract.IEcho" />
            <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex"/>
        </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>

</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you really looking at message level security? From your description, it appears that you want a transport level security (from IIS). For that you have to get your client configuration file correct. For example,

```
<binding ...
   ...
   <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
       <transport clientCredentialType="windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
...
```

This will ensure integrated windows authentication - will use current windows user running the client for authentication. For NTLM/BASIC authentication, you need to provide user name/password from code - for example,

```
<binding ...
       ...
       <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
           <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
```

And in code,

```
EchoService client = new EchoService("WSHttpBinding_IEcho");
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, pwd);
```

**EDIT**:

For basic authentication to work with http protocol, you have to do configuration on server side as well as. For example,

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <!-- SERVER -->
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="NewBinding">
                <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    ...
    <services>
        <service name="API.Proxy.EchoProxy" ...
           <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NewBinding" contract="API.Contract.IEcho" />
      ...
```

See [this article](http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2006/07/31/890.aspx) for more info. BTW, you may want to consider HTTPS scheme because basic auth transmits password in plain text.

Comment: @VinayC: Hello, thank you for helping. I have tried both your suggestions. I had to change the binding to basicHttpBinding; is that correct? The error message i receive for the 1st config change is `The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm="hostwebsite.local"'.`. The second error message where there was the config change and the authentication code, is the same as the first one i mentioned except the word Negotiate is replaced with Ntlm. thank you

Comment: @Valamas, for first config change to work, you have to allow integrated/windows authentication at IIS. Here, credentials of user logged in on client machine would be supplied to the server - this will not work if this user is not recognized on server. For using basic authentication scheme, you need to change clientCredentialType to basic, set realm value and in code, you have to set ClientCredentials.UserName (set user and password).

Comment: @VinayC: I am following the Basic Authentication path. Only Basic authentication is enabled in IIS. I have followed your last statement including realm which I have set to empty. In IIS, under Basic Authentication, the Realm and Domain fields are also empty.

Browsing to the service page returns error (`http://hostwebsite.local/Services/EchoService.svc`):
`Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service.`.... (continued)

Comment: If you wish to see the current config and code changes. [Here is a second zip](http://cid-e7737d00ff5b25e9.office.live.com/self.aspx/Public/WCF^_Authentication2.zip).

Comment: @Valamas, appologies - typically basic authentication is supposed to used with https. So to use with http, I believe you need to configure server side binding as well as, I have edited the answer to show that part.

Comment: thanks, looks like I am nearly there. I can now use a browser to pass authentication to view the wsdl. When I execute the client console, the error i get is `There was no endpoint listening at http://hostwebsite.local/Services/EchoService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.` The inner exception says 404 error. Weird! The echo code does work before all the security customisation. Looking at trace logs i see `Description Failed to lookup a channel to receive an incoming message. Either the endpoint or the SOAP action was not found.`

Comment: I have uploaded the current state of my project [WCF_Authentication3.zip](http://cid-e7737d00ff5b25e9.office.live.com/self.aspx/Public/WCF^_Authentication3.zip) and also the generated [Traces.svclog](http://cid-e7737d00ff5b25e9.office.live.com/self.aspx/Public/Traces.svclog). thank you

Comment: @VinayC: I have posted a question about this problem  at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507447/iis-status-200browser-404wcf

Comment: @VinayC: I have solved all my issues now. thank you so much for helping me.