# IIS status 200(Browser) - 404(Wcf)

Tags: c#, web-services, iis, wcf

I have a WCF service, IIS hosted. It is protected with Basic Authentication.

When I browse with a browser, I get a 401 (nt challenge) and a 200 (successful response).
The same website, page etc, with a WCF request via a console app, I get 401, then 404 (page not found).

Both use the same username and password which are correct. The machine is just a desktop for development. Not on a domain. The host is hostwebsite.local via host file binding to 127.0.0.1

Here are the IIS logs.
The first two lines are the failed WCF called. The last 2 lines is the successful browser call.

The only real difference is the GET/POST. The WCF works when authentication is anonymous.

How can I debug this issue? thank you.

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2011-03-31 22:53:58
#Fields: date time s-sitename s-computername s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs-version cs(User-Agent) cs(Cookie) cs(Referer) cs-host sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status sc-bytes cs-bytes time-taken
2011-03-31 22:56:37 W3SVC2 MIKEV-WS 127.0.0.1 POST /Services/EchoService.svc - 80 - 127.0.0.1 HTTP/1.1 - - - hostwebsite.local 401 2 5 6633 362 3
2011-03-31 22:56:37 W3SVC2 MIKEV-WS 127.0.0.1 POST /Services/EchoService.svc - 80 admin 127.0.0.1 HTTP/1.1 - - - hostwebsite.local 404 0 0 210 568 2
2011-03-31 22:57:07 W3SVC2 MIKEV-WS 127.0.0.1 GET /Services/EchoService.svc - 80 - 127.0.0.1 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+6.1;+en-US)+AppleWebKit/534.16+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/10.0.648.133+Safari/534.16 - - hostwebsite.local 401 2 5 6633 442 1
2011-03-31 22:57:10 W3SVC2 MIKEV-WS 127.0.0.1 GET /Services/EchoService.svc - 80 admin 127.0.0.1 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+6.1;+en-US)+AppleWebKit/534.16+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/10.0.648.133+Safari/534.16 - - hostwebsite.local 200 0 0 1287 485 23
```

#### New Information

Problem is now solved and I have listed the answer below.

Comment: what happens if you use GET from the console app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a configuration error causing the listening server to listen on `http://hostwebsite.local/Services/EchoService.svc/Services/EchoService.svc`

instead of

```
http://hostwebsite.local/Services/EchoService.svc
```

I cleared the address in the server endpoint which was `/Services/EchoService.svc`

```
<services>
    <service name="API.Proxy.EchoProxy" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
        <endpoint address="[CLEARED]" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="API.Contract.IEcho" bindingConfiguration="NewBinding" />
```

The client config already had the address

```
<client>
    <endpoint address="http://hostwebsite.local/Services/EchoService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecureBinding" contract="API.Contract.IEcho" name="SecureEndpoint">
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice your one request... is POST and the other is a GET... perhaps that is the issue!