# Using a property in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I have an Service which I'd like to use properties from my client:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyAPI
{
    string UserName { [OperationContract] get; [OperationContract] set; }
    string Password { [OperationContract] get; [OperationContract] set; }

    [OperationContract]
    bool StockQuery(string partNo);
}

public class MyAPI : IMyAPI
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    private void CheckSecurity()
    {
        if(this.UserName != "test" && this.Password != "123")
        {
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("Unauthorised");
        }
    }

    public bool StockQuery(string partNo)
    {
        this.CheckSecurity();
        if(partNo == "123456")
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then on my client I do:

```
Testing.MyAPIClient client = new Testing.MyAPIClient();

client.set_UserName("test");
client.set_Password("123");
Console.WriteLine(client.StockQuery("123456"));
Console.ReadLine();
```

The problem is, when I debug, `UserName` and `Password` are not being set, they're both null

Comment: Why the `set_UserName` and `set_Password`?  Is the client code still in C#, because normally you would just do `client.UserName = "test"`.

Comment: @CodingGorilla It is because the `OperationContract` is on the getter and setter explicitly, so it exposes the underlying method call

Comment: i doubt that you can "call" the property this way ... be aware of the session-mode as well - this might get messy as hell!

Comment: @JustinPihony Ahh, yea I missed that.  Yea, I agree with AndreasNiedermair, I think the OP needs to split his data members and operations into separate classes.

Comment: according to msdn (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/04f87191-f74d-48b7-b7eb-bb7fb91a0555/) your example should work ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF OperationContract property forgets value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533323/wcf-operationcontract-property-forgets-value)

Comment: The client is a seperate project in which Im referencing my service, I can't do `client.Username` thats why I had to do `client.set_Username`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

by default WCF will create a new instance of your service to service each call ([PerCall instancing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx#S1)) so your property sets are not going to be remembered.

You need to pass your security details with your `StockQuery` service call.

```
[OperationContract]
bool StockQuery(string partNo,String userName,String password);

public bool StockQuery(string partNo,String userName,String password)
{
    this.CheckSecurity(userName,password);
    if(partNo == "123456")
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You might get away with this approach using [PerSession instancing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx#S2), where the same instance will be used to service each client.

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
public interface IMyAPI
{
...
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)] 
public class MyAPI : IMyAPI
{
...
}
```

But rather then reinventing the wheel I'd look into using some of the [built in WCF security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735093.aspx).

Comment: Session=true is not possible?

Comment: I get the following error when I use PerSession instancing: `Contract requires Session, but Binding 'BasicHttpBinding' doesn't support it or isn't configured properly to support it.`

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff I suggest reading up on using sessions in WCF. I believe using nettcp binding supports it out of the box, but I'm not sure if that is appropriate for you.  BasicHttpBinding will require some more configuration

Comment: I've managed to fix it by using wsHttpBinding. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It should be PerSession by default? see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/sessions-instancing-and-concurrency#instancing)